# Submit a Form Variable to an API and print results

Tags: php, xml, forms, api

I am trying to create a form where a user can check their Gift Card Balance. The company we use has an API available. I wanted to be able to create a form where a user puts in their Name and Gift Card Number, hit submit, and return their card balance.

I created the form but am not to famililar with passing the variable to the api and parsing the xml results to a web page.

**API url:** http://apps.card9.com/api/?cmd=balance&card=**card Number**&key=**my api key**

I created a basic form:

```
<form action="balance.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
    Card #: <input type="text" name="cardId" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Php Script I tried using that I ran across:

```
if(isset($_POST['cardId'])){
    $userId = $_POST['cardId'];
    $obj = simplexml_load_file('http://apps.card9.com/api/?cmd=balance&card=' . $cardId . '&key=**my api Key**');
}else{
    // failed to load the xml
}
```

If anyone can help or point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: What is your question? Where are you getting stuck? I just see a bit of mangled code.

Comment: You set the variable $userId from the POST, then use $cardId in the API request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [simplexml_load_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) you should first see what the `$obj` is returning

```
print_r($obj);
```

Then you can determine what nodes you need to pull out:

```
$node = $obj->node;
```

or if there are hyphens in the node name

```
$node = $obj->{'node-name'};
```